# WP plugin that allows users to type in text then download it

Tags: wordpress, text, plugins, download, social-media

Greeting dear Wordpress Community,

I'm looking for a plugin that allow users to type in text then download it or share it to social media apps.

from your experience will I find something like that (Paid or free)

I appreciate your support dearly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library etc. are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes, nothing is impossible, you can create one for yourself, or have it created for you